# Не работает добавление css в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет всем

Есть такой jQuery код :

```
var parent = $(this).parents('.work-examples__li');
            var tarGet = parent.find(".example");
            var activeBlock = parent.find(".work-examples__li_active");
            var tarGetHeight = tarGet.height();

            if (!tarGet.hasClass('pop-up')) {
                tarGet.addClass('pop-up');
                activeBlock.addClass('visible');
                parent.css("padding-bottom", 'tarGetHeight')
```

При выполнении parent получает style="" (переменная не читается почему то), а если убираю скобки

```
parent.css("padding-bottom", tarGetHeight)
```

то паддинг получает 0px;

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
$(parent).css({"padding-bottom" : tarGetHeight});
```

Пробуйте. :)

**UPD**: я не сразу заметил. А как это вы так применяете jQuery функции? :) Исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Попробую. Не костыль ли это часом?Впервые вижу такую запись

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов Нет, это не костыль. Советую почитать оф. документацию: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Не заработало. Дает 0 пикселей

Comment: А что даёт `alert(tarGetHeight);`? Может у вас в саму `tarGetHeight` принимается 0?

Comment: Нет, я через консоль выводил -417 px

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов обновил ответ. Пробуйте. :)

Comment: Тут без разницы, это же переменная. Она может использоваться и без &. Я попробовал - тот же результат. Может, контекст не тот.

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов никогда у меня она так не работала, сколько я ни пробовал. Вы хотя бы попробуйте, а уж потом будем думать. Например, в оф. доках встречается `$(this).css();`. Но ведь `this` это просто переменная. Почему тогда не `this.css();`. Логично ведь? ;)

Comment: Нашел проблему. Действительно, переменная не получает высоту. Я пробовал через консоль браузера и там работало, а именно из кода нет. Ваш код рабочий :)

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов вот и отлично. Рад что разобрались. Удачной вам работы. :)

Comment: И вам :) Хорошего дня